# How to build std::map to functions overloaded for derived class

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-function

I want to build an std::map to a set of functions taking a Base object, while also being overloaded for a particular Derived class. In case the function were not overloaded, the setup would be the following:

```
#include <functional> 

bool func_1( const Base& );
bool func_2( const Base& );

std::map< std::string, std::function< bool (const Base&) > > funcMap = {
    { "a", func_1 },
    { "b", func_2 }
};
```

This works without problems. But now if I would have a class Derived inheriting from Base :

```
class Derived : public Base {
    ...
}
```

and add an overloaded version of the "func_1":

```
bool func_1( const Base& );
bool func_2( const Base& );
bool func_1( const Derived& );
std::map< std::string, std::function< bool (const Base&) > > funcMap = {
    { "a", func_1 },
    { "b", func_2 }
};
```

it will no longer compile, giving the error:

```
error: could not convert ‘{{"a", func_1},{"b", func_2}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::function<bool(const Base&)> >’
```

Naively I would have assumed that since the map is defined with a template argument of std::function< bool (const Base&) > it would be able to correctly match the func_1 object to the one taking the Base argument, but apparently this is not the case. Is there a way to fix or circumvent this problem?

Comment: What you are trying to do is unsafe. What if someone derives another type from `Base` pass that object to your method, now upcast to accept `Base&` but expecting a `Derived&` and in reality getting something else. How would it behave at runtime?

Comment: Part of the type of a function is the type of its arguments.  I don't think there's any way around that, even with templates.

Comment: Tanveer, I am not sure what you mean exactly. In the actual setup, func_1( const Base& ) always returns the correct result, but can take a shortcut when knowing the object is of a particular derived class.

Comment: And to respond to Mark. I understand that an object of type Derived is also of type Base, but when simply defining func_1 and its overloaded version and using them, the compiler seems to be able to correctly determine the types. So I wonder if someone can explain the difference between that and the template argument to the map in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to cast the function pointer to the type you need and the compiler will select the correct overload for the type you are casting to:

```
{"a", (bool(*)(const Base&))func_1 },
```

This isn't so clean, and function pointer syntax can be confusing, but it is what's needed to make that code work

I didn't realize that the c-cast will compile even if there is no function that actually matches the signature, so this solution is safer:

```
{"a", static_cast<bool(*)(const Base&)>(func_1)}
```

Also, while we're at it, you could also use a lambda:

```
{"a", [](const Base & o) { return func_1(o); } }
```

Comment: Not sure why the pointer is needed, since I was passing function references in the first place?

Comment: Actually, passing functions around is only ever done via function pointers. When you pass the function name here, it gets converted to a pointer to the function for you by the compiler. However, the compiler treats casting to a function type and casting to a pointer to a function type differently and a function pointer can only be cast to a pointer to a function type.

Comment: @W.Verbeke similar to arrays, functions decay to pointers all the time.

Comment: Ok interesting, did not know that. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I would use a `static_cast` instead. With a c-cast the smallest typo can have bad effects, especially true for function pointers

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think the OP is trying to call the `const Derived&` overload, he's trying to get the compiler to select the `const Base&` overload. That was my understanding of his question. I may also be misunderstanding your comment.

Comment: @SirGuy you are right, I misread the question.  I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a wrapper function to call to the flat function that expects a Derived instance passed to it.  The wrapper  just does a dynamic_cast (or static_cast) and invokes the desired function.

```
bool func_1( const Base& );
bool func_2( const Base& );
bool func_3( const Derived& );

bool func_3_wrapper(const Base &b) {
    const Base *pB = &b;
    const Derived *pD = dynamic_cast<D*>(pB);
    return pD ? func_3(*pD) : return false;
}

std::map< std::string, std::function< bool (const Base&) > > funcMap = {
    { "a", func_1 },
    { "b", func_2 },
    { "c", func_3_wrapper }
};
```

Alternatively, since your map values are std::function instances, you could do a lambda.

```
std::map< std::string, std::function< bool (const Base&) > > funcMap = {
    { "a", func_1 },
    { "b", func_2 },
    { "c", [](const Base &b)->bool {
             auto pD = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&b);
             return pD ? func_3(*pD) : false;
           }}
};
```

Comment: I'm glad you added the normal version of `func_3_wrapper`, I was going to ask why you used a lambda where it clearly wasn't needed.